# SQL COUNT function query as per same column value

Tags: sql, count

Am kind of new to sql and I have just come with a situation as shown below.
the query that i have so far outputs wrong results i.e

$query = "SELECT sch_name, dist_name COUNT(sch_name) AS total_sch FROM school ORDER BY dist_name";

**school**

```
  **sch_name**   **dist_name**
    kaoma        lusaka
    kaloma       lusaka
    momba        mansa
    kebwi        mansa
    matero       ndola

EXPECTED OUTPUT

   **dist_name**     **total_sch**
     lusaka            2
     mansa             2
     ndola             1
```

Comment: At a guess, is this [tag:mysql]? If so (and even if not) please edit your question and add a suitable tag for your RDBMS product.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT dist_name, COUNT(sch_name) total_sch
FROM school
GROUP BY dist_name
ORDER BY dist_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select dist_name,Count(*) total_sch
From School
Group By dist_name
Order By Count(*)
```

Comment: or SELECT dist_name, COUNT(dist_name) as total_sch
FROM school
GROUP BY dist_name, COUNT(dist_name)
ORDER BY COUNT(dist_name)

Comment: thanks buddy <Jithin Shaji> how can i contact u, for more lessons?

Comment: This is a great place to learn,http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/ff898410